# Refrigerant coolant Line is Leaking

Tags: hvac

Yesterday only, I noticed that a whistling sound coming from Refrigerant coolant Line. Its in basement. I think its coming from inside. what could be the problem ?

[image]

Comment: With your thermostat set to cool, and temp set warm so it doesn’t try to run the AC, switch the fan from auto to on, then check for the whistling. That will tell you if it is refrigerant or just the circulating air. A refrigerant leak loud enough to whistle wouldn’t leak very long before it was empty.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I just kept the fan ON and AC mode off.  it seems its just a circulating  air, that means something inside is leaking and has to be sealed ?  its not good from energy point of view.

Comment: If refrigerant were leaking, you would soon see frost on the a/c ducts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just an air leak, inside that box is the evaporator coil air flows over the coils in the box and sometimes the pressure inside finds a way out.
You can seal it, foam or putty is common.

If it was a refrigerant leak that you heard your system would be out of refrigerant in a short time.

Is there a problem with air leaking here? Not really it’s just some air that is not going where it could be I do try to seal these up with putty because opening the system to clean foams sometimes have to be cut off where putty can be removed and reused in the future for maintenance.

Comment: Is the air leaking from inside the cabinet common?

Comment: Yes it is common, if inside a conditioned air space or inside the home, it usually is not a problem. If outside the conditioned airspace it makes a big difference and we do seal them.